# Are Android updates encrypted?

Tags: updates

We are seeing weird traffic in our network. We opened today the update of Android devices and capturingvtrafgic we see encoded, binary or encrypted data over port 80.

Are Android updates encrypted?
What protocol is used?

Comment: one can assume that Android does not send updates in a format that can be intercepted and modified in transit

Comment: In security I do not assume anything :) I'm looking for documentation, facts...I have searched Google but the there a lot of noise because there appear a lot of sites related to Android encryption but not updates.

Comment: But this is an operational detail: they might choose best practices one time, but not another. Your question is, is the most recent update delivered encrypted, which is not a security question.

Comment: Android updates frequently come in the form of a flashable `zip`. The file in question is not encrypted, as its main security measure is a cryptographic RSA signature inside its `META-INF` directory.